# Can physics proofs be totally formalized?

Tags: proof-verification, physics

I don't have a lot of experience with physics beyond minimal potential energy and forces. I recently saw cool proofs in geometry using physics, such as Fermat-Torricelli point. The proof appears here in pages 4,5
http://www.cmi.ac.in/~vipul/olymp_resources/olympiadarticles/geometricoptimization.pdf

Is there a way to make those proofs mathematically formal?

Comment: A couple of calculations of the position of Fermat-Torricelli point can be found, for instance, on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point). One is in sinthetic geometry, others use calculus tools.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli what does that have to do with my question?

Comment: It might help for the related question "How is a properly formalized proof of Fermat-Torricelli theorem?". Whether or not anyone can provide a proper mathematical formalization of a proof you've seen somewhere, it largely depends on whether (s)he has ever seen it too.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I don't exactly understand, but maybe i phrased my question badly, I am aware of rigorous proofs, I'm only interested if this lovely one can be formalized

Comment: And my point is "This"="???".

Comment: @G.Sassatelli point taken, I'll edit a reference. Thanks!